# I cant find my Minecraft Screenshots anywhere, i have looked at %appdata%/.minecraft Does anyone else know a way i can view them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cant find my screenshots folder anywhere, its not in the app data folders, I am just wondering if there is any other way to view my screenshots or if I could somehow get my screenshots folder back to where its supposed to be. I have already tried to look in all my other folders on this computer, but its still no where to be found. I would just like to know if anyone could help resolve this problem as I would like to view my photos that I took on mine-craft a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Minecraft's screenshot button, then the file should be here:

`C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\screenshots`

If they are not there, there could several things wrong, such as Minecraft is placing the pictures in your computer's pictures folder, or a whole new thing entirely. If you cannot find the screenshots in

`C:\Users\Computer\OneDrive\Pictures`

You might need to search through all your files. To do this, open File Explorer, go to the search box on the top right and type the year of the photo, then a dash, then the month, dash, then the day, and by then it should bring it up.
For example, if I wanted a screenshot from March 23rd, 2018, I would search
"`2018-03-23`" and the file should come up if it is anywhere on your computer.

Comment: If that doesn't do it then they are not on your computer.